# FLAGS in python Constructor?

Tags: python, constructor

What are FLAGS in python constructors? I've seen them being used in many examples without any import statement. One such example is below.

```
class DAE:

    def __init__(self, FLAGS):
        ''' Imlimentation of deep autoencoder class.'''

        self.FLAGS=FLAGS
```

Also, they've been used in methods like this

```
self.FLAGS.num_h
```

But I couldn't find `num_h` being intialized anywhere. I am not able to find more details on FLAGS on the internet either (I might be searching it in the wrong context).

EDIT: Figured it out. Found a function/Object named FLAGS which uses `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` in the main file. Here it is just passed as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: Looks to be just a regular argument

Comment: Looks like a class with properties. In this case num_h is a property of the object FLAGS. You can access it with FLAGS.num_h as in the example and probably set it like FLAGS.num_h = 20. Find more about properties  here:  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Exactly. Found a function/object named FLAGS which uses tf.app.flags.FLAGS in the main file. Here it was just passed as an argument. Thanks.